# How can I interact with a Vagrant shell provisioning script?

Tags: heroku, vagrant

I have a shell provisioning script that invokes a command that requires user input - but when I run `vagrant provision`, the process hangs at that point in the script, as the command is waiting for my input, but there is nowhere to give it. Is there any way around this - i.e. to force the script to run in some interactive mode?

The specifics are that I creating a clean Ubuntu VM, and then invoking the Heroku CLI to download a database backup (this is in my provisioning script):

```
curl -o /tmp/db.backup `heroku pgbackups:url -a myapp`
```

However, because this is a clean VM, and therefore this is the first time that I have run an  Heroku CLI command, I am prompted for my login credentials. Because the script is being managed by Vagrant, there is no interactive shell attached, and so the script just hangs there.

Comment: what was your solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass temporary input or variables to a Vagrant script, you can have them enter their credentials as temporary environment variables for that command by placing them first on the same line:

```
username=x password=x vagrant provision
```

and access them from within Vagrantfile as

```
$u = ENV['username']
$p = ENV['password']
```

Then you can pass them as an argument to your bash script:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline: "echo username: $1, password: $2"
    s.args: [$u, $p]
end
```

You can install something like expect in the vm to handle passing those variables to the curl command.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't want to hard code your credentials in plain text thus trying to force an interactive mode. 
Thing is just as you I don't see such option in vagrant provision doc ( http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/shell.html ) so one way or another you need to embed the authentication within your script.
Have you thought about using something like getting a token and use the heroku REST Api instead of the CLI?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication

Comment: You're right - I'm building a generic box for a group of developers, all of whom need to supply their own credentials. I've worked around the problem for now.

Comment: @JoeBlock you can work around it by using a config file that users enter data in pre-emptively, and expect: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect